# Has anyone successfully imported animations from Blender 2.8 into Xcode?

Tags: xcode, arkit, blender, realitykit, reality-converter

Lately I have been having problems importing animations from Blender into Xcode for use with augmented reality projects.  Up until recently I was able to import the models with their animations as .dae files which could then be converted within Xcode to .scn files.  Following this process now results in a crash merely by selecting the .dae file within Xcode before I am able to convert to a .scn file, and in many cases .dae and .scn files which were previously successfully imported now crash once selected in older projects.

I have tried taking another approach which involves exporting the files from Blender as .usdc and then converting them within RealityConverter into a .usdz file which Apple now supports within RealityKit, this is unsuccessful as RealityKit does not support Y-up ecosystems such as Blender.

Xcode also seems to be having issues properly displaying any selected object within SceneKit as the objects now are hard to view due to some sort of rendering issue.  I updated Xcode to 11.4.1 and this problem persists.

I greatly appreciate any support with these issues and I hope everyone else using ARKit and RealityKit have had an easier time importing their animated content!

[Viewport Rendering Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmRJR.jpg)